# Find part of a string in CSV and replace whole cell with new entry?

Tags: python, bash, csv, awk, sed

I've got a CSV file with a column which I want to sift through. I want to use a pattern file to find all entries where the pattern exists even in part of the column's value, and replace the whole cell value with this "pattern".
I made a list of keywords that I want to use as my "pattern" bank; 
So, if a cell in this column (this case only second) has this "pattern" as part of its string, then I want to replace the whole cell with this "pattern".

so for example:

my target file:

```
id1,Taxidermy Equipment & Supplies,moreinfo1
id2,Taxis & Private Hire,moreinfo2
id3,Tax Services,moreinfo3
id4,Tools & Hardware,moreinfo4
id5,Tool Sharpening,moreinfo5
id6,Tool Shops,moreinfo6
id7,Video Conferencing,moreinfo7
id8,Video & DVD Shops,moreinfo8
id9,Woodworking Equipment & Supplies,moreinfo9
```

my "pattern" file:

```
Taxidermy Equipment & Supplies
Taxis
Tax Services
Tool
Video
Wood
```

output file:

```
id1,Taxidermy Equipment & Supplies,moreinfo1
id2,Taxis,moreinfo2
id3,Tax Services,moreinfo3
id4,Tool,moreinfo4
id5,Tool,moreinfo5
id6,Tool,moreinfo6
id7,Video,moreinfo7
id8,Video,moreinfo8
id9,Wood,moreinfo9
```

I came up with the usual "find and replace" sed:

```
sed -i 's/PATTERN/REPLACE/g' file.csv
```

but I want it to run on a specific column, so I came up with:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="|"}$2==PATTERN{$2=REPLACE}{print}' file.csv
```

but it doesn't work on "part of string" ([Video]:"Video & DVD Shops" -> "Video") and I can't seem to get it how awk takes input as a file for the "Pattern" block.

Is there an awk script for this? Or do I have to write something (in python with the built in csv suit for example?)

Comment: You can do it in awk, whatever it is, but you've left out the interesting/hard to handle use cases of what you want to happen if 2 "patterns" match the target field or if there's a partial match instead of whole word matches (e.g. Tax against Taxi) or if a "pattern" is a substring of another "pattern" or the "pattern" contains regexp metacharacters or if it contains backreferences or....

Comment: I guess I'm sifting through a whole bunch of data so a couple of exceptions dont bother me that much as long as I can get the most of it. Thank for the note anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In awk, using `index`. It only prints record if a replacement is made but it's easy to modify to printing even if there is no match (for example replace the `print $1,i,$3}` with `$0=$1 OFS i OFS $3} 1`):

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, '
NR==FNR { a[$1]; next }          # store "patterns" to a arr
        { for(i in a)            # go thru whole a for each record
              if(index($2,i))    # if "pattern" matches $2
                  print $1,i,$3  # print with replacement
        }
' pattern_file target_file
id1,Taxidermy Equipment & Supplies,moreinfo1
id2,Taxis,moreinfo2
id3,Tax Services,moreinfo3
id4,Tool,moreinfo4
id5,Tool,moreinfo5
id6,Tool,moreinfo6
id7,Video,moreinfo7
id8,Video,moreinfo8
id9,Wood,moreinfo9
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the explanation, Its exactly the AWK that I was looking for and I even learned a thing from it!

Comment: Hey, I got into trouble by not filtering my patterns, so I decided to make the Pattern file into a two column csv. First column is what to search for and second one is what to print instead. I tired messing around with the script but I cant force it into working with this "array" and it cries about "i" being a scalar. Any chance you could take another look at this? I guess I got to "split" my new patternfile, don't I?

Comment: You should make that a new question and post new sample files with it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the fast reply, but I already got that figured out. For those that may find this useful heres what did the trick for me:                                            awk '
    BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," } 
    FNR == NR { 
        split($0, f, /:/)
        map[f[1]] = f[2]
        next 
    } 
    { 
        for (i=2; i<=2; i++) { 
            if ($i in map) { $i = map[$i] } 
        } 
    } 
    { print }
' mapfile csvfile

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution, using [Text::CSV_XS](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV_XS):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Text::CSV_XS qw{ csv };

my ($input_file, $pattern_file) = @ARGV;

open my $pfh, '<', $pattern_file or die $!;
chomp( my @patterns = <$pfh> );

my $aoa = csv(in => $input_file);
for my $line (@$aoa) {
    for my $pattern (@patterns) {
        if (-1 != index $line->[1], $pattern) {
            $line->[1] = $pattern;
            last
        }
    }
}

csv(in => $aoa, quote_space => 0, eol => "\n", out => \*STDOUT);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, its been a while since I used a perl script - but I guess sometime ill have to sit down and work on it - so why not now!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a (mostly) awk solution:

```
#/bin/bash

patterns_regex=`cat patterns_file  | tr '\n' '|'`
cat target_file | awk -F"," -v patterns="$patterns_regex" '
BEGIN {
    OFS=",";
    split(patterns, patterns_split, "|");
}

{
    for (pattern_num in patterns_split) {
        pattern=patterns_split[pattern_num];
        if (pattern != "" && $2 ~ pattern) {
            print $1,pattern,$3
        }
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to solve this with `sed`, you will need some steps.
For each pattern you will need a command like

```
sed 's/^\([^,]*\),\(.*Tool.*\),/\1,Tool,/' inputfile
```

You will need each pattern twice, you can translate the  patternfile with

```
sed 's/.*/"&" "&"/' patternfile
# Change the / into #, thats easier for the final command
sed 's#.*#"&" "&"#' patternfile
```

When you instruct sed to read a commandfile, you do need to start each line with `sed`. The commandfile will look like

```
sed 's#.*#s/^\\([^,]*\\),\\(.*&.*\\),/\\1,&,/#;s#&#\\&#g'  patternfile
```

You can store this is a file and use the file, but with process substitution you can do things like

```
cat <(echo "Now this line from echo is handled as a file")
```

Nice. Lets test the solution

```
sed -f <(sed 's#.*#s/^\\([^,]*\\),\\(.*&.*\\),/\\1,&,/#'  patternfile) inputfile
```

Almost there! Only the first output line is strange. Whats happening?
The first pattern has a `&`, and that has a special meaning.
We can patch our command by adding a backslash in the pattern:

```
sed -f <(sed 's#.*#s/^\\([^,]*\\),\\(.*&.*\\),/\\1,&,/#;s#&#\\&#g' patternfile) inputfile
```

Comment: Thank for the lengthy explanation! I've never delved so deep into sed, should look it up seriously sometime on the weekend.